# implement automatic realated ,upsell, cross sell products

Tags: up-sells, cross-sells, related-products

how to implement automatic Related , upsell, cross-sell products.
we uploaded lot of products. but there is no **Related , upsell, cross sell products.**

What we want is through programatically how we can assign the Related , upsell, cross sell for **same category** products.
Is there any free extension that give this result with atleast 4 + review.

Comment: Did you find any free stuff?

Comment: @Rathinam i did't found.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AheadWorks Automatic Related Products 2 `https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/automatic-related-products-2.html`

43 reviews

5 Stars support

FREE MODULES:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/related-products-manager.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mtoo-related-automatic-related-products.html

Comment: sorry, i am looking for some free extension.

Comment: I don't suggest to do, I have been looking for the same function for ages and this is the best module to use. I'm not working for AheadWorks :D -  Update me answer with 2 free modules

Comment: Nice , I will wait for some time. if i get free extension thats much better. although you are not working for ahead works, as you are suggesting ahead works, It shows the quality of that extension. :)

Comment: I have used the same module in few project and it works with no issues

Comment: if are interested to purchase paid module then see [magento 2 automatic related products](https://www.mageants.com/automatic-related-products-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension for upsell

Answer (score 2):

You can check in DB how this is related...

`catalog_product_link`table holds "link_type_id"(here you can check which id upsell or cross sell have), and then you just need to insert products to the table `catalog_product_link` and set the riht link_type_id to it. Best way to do this is to have some excel or something like that, map all products to its linked product id and just build insert queries and boom:)
Clear cache, maybe you will need some reindexing - I am not sure about that and you should have related products on site.